# How do I write test react-apollo component using updateQuery to update query

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I have a handler on my react component. `handleInputChange` and here is the code.

```js
handleInputChange = (e, roomCapacity = 0) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value }, () => {
      const { location, search, office } = this.state;
      this.props.data.fetchMore({
        variables: {
          page: 1,
          perPage: 5,
          capacity: roomCapacity,
          location: search || location,
          office,
        },
        updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
          return { ...fetchMoreResult }
        },
      }).catch((err) => {
        notification(toastr, 'error', err.graphQLErrors[0].message)();
      });
    });
  };
```

I have written some test that passes but I want to write test to cover the `updateQuery` function. See image below of where I want to write tests to cover. [See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KazqI.png)

Please someone should help me, I have searched online and seem not to find. Thanks